# Deep Copy/Clone methods in a C# class hierarchy - Do I need a concrete implementation everywhere?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Let's say I have the following class hierarchy (base interface included):

```
IAction -> (abstract) BaseAction -> (concrete) ImmediateAction -> (concrete) MovementAction
```

Now, let's say IAction exposes a method (well, really a different interface that IAction implements does but let's keep things simple here!):

```
// Returns a new IAction instance deep copied from the current instance.
IAction DeepClone();
```

Good so far? We have our deep copy method, and `ImmediateAction` has some properties that it wants copied so it will provide not only an implementation of `DeepClone()`, but a copy constructor as well:

```
//Base Action implementation
protected BaseAction(BaseAction old)
{
    this.something = old.something;
}

//Immediate Action Implementation
protected ImmediateAction(ImmediateAction old)
   : base(old)
{
    this.anything = old.anything;
}

public IAction DeepClone()
{
    return new ImmediateAction(this);
}
```

Now, let's say `MovementAction` doesn't have anything inside of it that's relevant in a `DeepClone()` at all, so it doesn't implement the method or a copy constructor.

The problem that I'm having is this:

```
IAction x = new MovementAction();
IAction y = x.DeepClone();

//pleaseBeTrue is false
bool pleaseBeTrue = y is MovementAction;
```

Now, I understand what's going on here - `MovementAction` does not implement `DeepClone()`, so `ImmediateAction.DeepClone()` is called instead, which instantiates a new `ImmediateAction`. Hence, the type of `y` in the above example is `ImmediateAction` instead of `MovementAction`.

So, after this lengthy preamble, my question is this: what is the best practice for this type of situation? Am I stuck? Do I simply *have* to implement a `DeepClone()` method  *no matter what* for every class along the hierarchy? Is the pattern that I am using here incorrect, and there's *a better way*?

One final note: I would like to avoid reflection if at all possible.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid reflection?

Comment: This is being used in a game, and potentially during gameplay and not just loading, so I'd like to avoid the overhead of reflection if at all possible. A little background: Typically things ar eloaded in via JSON/XML definitions, but the IAction factory (and other factories) cache IActions by type, and clone the stored reference to avoid going back to XML for loading again. (Pooling was another option, but with so many potential types of actions, all with different properties and such I can't see a pooling solution being feasible either without potentially hundreds of different pool)

Comment: Seems to me an issue of intent.  If you plan on handling things as `IAction`s and it is important to conserve the original type of whatever objects you've called `DeepClone` on, you'd write the `DeepClone` on all of those concrete classes that implement `IAction` and that would ensure you get the right kind of object created.  Fortunately, it's trivial to write those.

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose I was fishing for some magical solution that perhaps I wasn't seeing (or perhaps a "no you idiot, that's not how you set up a `DeepClone`! This is how..) but I guess the simple solution of "don't be lazy, implement `DeepClone` for your concrete classes!" is just how it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use an extension method and do incremental cloning

```
public static class DeepCopyExt
{
    public static T DeepCopy<T>(this T item)
        where T : ThingBase, new()
    {
        var newThing = new T();
        item.CopyInto(newThing);
        return newThing;
    }
}

public abstract class ThingBase
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public virtual void CopyInto(ThingBase target)
    {
        target.A = A;
    }
}

public class ThingA : ThingBase
{
}

public class ThingB : ThingA
{
    public int B { get; set; }

    public override void CopyInto(ThingBase target)
    {
        var thingB = target as ThingB;

        if(thingB == null)
        {
           throw new ArgumentException("target is not a ThingB");
        }

        thingB.B = B;
        base.CopyInto(thingB);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new ThingB
        {
            A = 1,
            B = 3
        };

        //c is ThingB
        var c = b.DeepCopy();

        var b1 = new ThingA
        {
            A = 1,
        };

        //c1 is ThingA
        var c1 = b1.DeepCopy();

        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to say, I like this solution! There's one less thing to implement per-class (`CopyInto` rather than `DeepClone` and a copy constructor) <I>and</I> it puts the object instantiation into a single location, rather than spread throughout a million `DeepClone()`s, so pooling might become an easier addition too! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So yes, you have two options:

- Either implement DeepClone() each time and in details (list all not-shared properties)
- Or use 'quick&dirty' but shared implementation using reflection

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd need to implement your clone method in the concrete classes. In fact this code you posted won't compile if ImmediateAction is abstract like you said at the top:

```
return new ImmediateAction(this);
```

Comment: Ah, that was my mistake. Immediate isn't abstract.